# How can I write several binaries in a json file without using byte[]?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am working in a REST API using Spring Boot, and I need to generate a JSON file with some data, and send that file to the client. Some of this data are simple Strings, but I also need to include some binaries inside it. So, an example of the JSON file generated could be:

```
{  
   "result":"0",
   "message":"",
   "document":{  
      "data":{ 
         "tag1":"String",
         "tag2":"String"
      }, 
      "binary": {
          "type": "application/pdf",
          "content" ${BINARY_CONTENT}
      }
   }
}
```

The way I was doing it is by using a Java Object with several properties, and "content" property was a byte[]. However, the files handled can be large (even several GB), so I can not use an array of bytes: the memory will fill up, and also byte[] length is limmited it int_maxSize.

How can I generate the JSON file without using byte[]? For example, handling the InputStream directly. The idea is generate a JSON file (which size can be GB), read it, and then send it as binary to the client. I cannot store the full binary in memory because its size can be large.

Thank you.

Comment: You could write your binary content to files, into cloud storage or on your own servers as I don't know your environment, and in your json just add paths of the files so the user can download them.

Comment: You might try something along the above comment lines and if you have problems post something about it.  You answered your own question, you can't do what you want simply with a JSON file.

Comment: JSON isn't appropriate for transfering such amounts of data. Your transfer is dominated by the binary data. So you better design your transfer format around it. You could e.g. use a zip file. The first entry would be the JSON file without the binary data. The following entries would contain the binary data. Zip files can be generated on the fly if this is helpful for your solution, i.e. you don't need to copy the files to the file system, zip them and trasnmit it.